# Javascript: How to save ArrayBuffer when the script is rendering from server side?

Tags: javascript

The script file is rendered from server side, and when I using the code as below to download data from the script

```js
const blob = new Blob([data]);
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = "1.mp4";
a.click();
URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
```

it shows that `document is not defined`. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem through split the code into two parts.

1. While server side rendering, I print the blob's url in console:

```js
const blob = new Blob([data]);
console.log(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

2. And While client side rendering, I download the blob manually:

```js
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = 'blob:{paste the url address}';
a.download = "1.mp4";
a.click();
URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
```